# logic to convert this array to a string using loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a database query string which should be like this,

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM states WHERE country_id = 121 ) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cities WHERE country_id = 121 ) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM areas WHERE country_id = 121) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM states WHERE country_id = 122) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cities WHERE country_id = 122) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM areas WHERE country_id = 122)
```

for that i have used the code like this.

```
$id = array('121','122');
$table = array('states','cities','areas');
$loopCount = count($id) * count($table);
$queryString = array();
for($i=0;$i<$loopCount;$i++)
{
    $queryString[] = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table[$i] WHERE country_id = $id[$i] ) + ";
}
```

i know the above code is totally wrong, what will be the correct way to implement the code to get desired result?

Update :

i would like to get the total number of counts From country_id not individual, that can exist in 1 to three tables, the below query seems to work fine for me, but please do let me know if you have a better solution

```
SELECT( 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM states WHERE country_id IN(121,122)) + 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cities WHERE country_id IN(121,122) ) +
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM areas WHERE country_id IN(121,122) )
      );
```

Comment: Please benchmark your query with `EXPLAIN`. I'd be surprised if this'd be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed the last few comments, give this a try

```
$countryCodes = array(121, 122);
$countryCodeString = implode($countryCodes, ', ');

$sql = 
  "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(S.id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(C.id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(A.id)) as desired_sum 
   FROM states S
        JOIN cities C ON S.country_id = C.country_id
        JOIN areas A ON A.country_id = S.country_id
   WHERE s.country_id in ($countryCodes)";

$res = mysql_query($sql);
$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$val = $arr['desired_sum'];
```

So this will give a single integer, the total count of any 'unit' (city, state, or area) within any of the countries specified in `$countryCodes`.  It does assume that there is at least one state in each country.  (ie - if country X has cities and areas within it but no states, those cities and areas wont be counted).  Also assumes that the primary keys of `states`, `cities`, `areas` are `state_id`, `city_id` and `area_id` (not simply `id`)

Comment: that's what even i got confused the primary keys are just id's not state_id, or city_id, or area_id.. anyway thanks ill test and let you know

Comment: my primary key is just id and foreign key is country_id,state_id,city_id,area_id etc. when i use your code it gives me this error. Unknown column 'states.country_id' in 'where clause'   i have used the following code  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(s.id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)) AS desired_sum FROM states s JOIN cities c on s.country_id = c.country_id JOIN areas a on a.country_id = s.country_id WHERE states.country_id IN(118)

Comment: wooow, thank you so much after a very long lasting testing and much patience i not only understood the code, but got it to work brilliantly. all thanks to you... :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
$id = array('121', '122');
```

[jon_darkstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475993/jon-darkstar)'s count (Thank you!):

```
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(state_id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(city_id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(area_id)) as desired_sum
```

JOIN another table called `cities` with the same `country_id`

```
LEFT JOIN cities ON states.country_id = cities.country_id
```

JOIN another table called `areas` with the same `country_id`

```
LEFT JOIN areas ON states.country_id = areas.country_id
```

Filter results for `country_id`'s you provided in your array, implode them with a php function, called [implode()](http://hu.php.net/implode).

```
WHERE states.country_id IN (" . implode(', ', $id) . ")"
```

OR, within a foreach loop where `$cid` will be your country_id (see jon_darkstar's comment below)

```
WHERE states.country_id = " . $cid . ""
```

A single one query:

```
"SELECT * FROM states, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(state_id)) + 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(city_id)) + 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(area_id)) AS desired_sum
        JOIN `cities` ON states.country_id = cities.country_id
        JOIN `areas` ON states.country_id = areas.country_id
        WHERE states.country_id IN (" . implode(', ', $id) . ")";
```

Comment: the problem is i want to do it dynamically, because $id can have more then one value and as many as it can be, and $value can have 1 to 3 values.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary casting, you might want to remove the quotation marks around 121 and 122 (since this is a number field).

Comment: just updated my snippet so you can use many variables dynamically.

Comment: @fabrik i am unable to understand your code, i will be glad if you could try explaining on what is happening with that query. sorry but i am still learning things :)

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar Please read the linked MySQL documentation page too, but i'll try to summarize what happens. See my update on my answer.

Comment: but this count will be too big wont it? If I understand correctly, he wants the sum of `states`, `cities`, `areas` with a certain country. (ie. 10 cities + 20 areas + 2 states = 32) this will give all combinations (ie. 10 cities * 20 areas * 2 states = 400)

Comment: @jon_darkstar You're right. In that case OP may want to get each country in a different query.

Comment: actually, what if he uses the same joins that you have but `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(state_id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(city_id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(area_id)) as desired_sum` ?  I always wish i had a convenient means of testing for questions like this...

Comment: @jon_darkstar thank you but it'd rude if i'll post your answer wouldn't it?

Comment: @Jon_daskar yes you understood me correctly the above one gives me 40 result i was wondering what was happening until i saw your comment.

Comment: sure i guess ill post, although i usually like to be more sure that its correct first =P    thanks fabrik

Comment: what i want to know is total count that's it, i want to check the numbers of country_id in states, cities and areas table

Comment: nah you keep it fabrik, got half way thru writing and lost interest =P was mostly you anyhow.  thanks anyway i appreciate

Comment: @jon_darkstar please post your answer i think OP could accept it.

Comment: lol @jon-darkstar i was waiting for your post though :), can you please have a look at my post once again, i have updated it, as i am still unable to understand if your solution can get me my desired result, i would appreciate if you could try posting your solution differently :)

Comment: @fabrik can you please make the query one single code with jon_darkstar solution? and your's too? thank you

Comment: your code combined with jon_darkstars solution gives me this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN cities ON states.country_id = ciities.country_id JOIN areas ON states.' at line 1

Comment: @Ibrahim you wrote ciities insead of cities.

Comment: @fabrik i used this query  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(state_id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(city_id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(area_id)) AS desired_sum JOIN cities ON states.country_id = cities.country_id JOIN areas ON states.country_id = areas.country_id WHERE states.country_id = 118          and still i am getting this error  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN cities ON states.country_id = cities.country_id JOIN areas ON states.countr' at line 1

Comment: @jon_darkstar from my answer: *"OR, within a foreach loop where $cid will be your country_id (see jon_darkstar's comment below)"*

Comment: ok gotcha.  i never recommended a for loop tho, isnt that the whole thing we trying to avoid?  this would be almost trivial if we used several queries

Comment: @jon_darkstar yup, modified again. :o

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$a=array();
$a[]=array('states','121');
$a[]=array('cities','121');
$a[]=array('areas','121');
$a[]=array('states','122');
$a[]=array('cities','122');
$a[]=array('areas','122');

$r=array();
foreach($a as $v)
    $r[]='(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '.$v[0].' WHERE country_id = '.$v[1].' )';
$r=implode(' + ',$r);
?>
```

But I'd highly advise against this approach to get what it seems you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of queries, but I don't think trying an `UNION` would be so much better. My advice is to improve the queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM states WHERE country_id IN (121, 122) GROUP BY country_id
```

Now you have one query per table.
On the php side you could do this:

```
$id = array('121','122');
$table = array('states','cities','areas');
foreach($table as $tableName) {
    $queryString[] = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM {$tableName} WHERE country_id IN (". implode(',', $id) .") GROUP BY country_id"
}
```

Comment: this looks interesting, let me try and get back to you